# Codeception: avoid substring using by see method

Tags: php, codeception

I have a big problem with codeception. It seems that It checks the strings (passed to the see method) as a substring.

```
    $I->dontSee('Car A 1', 'ul li');
    $I->see('Car A 1 1', 'ul li');
```

Unfortunately the `dontSee` will be failed. Because it find the `'Cart A 1'` string in the `'Car A 1 1'` string...

Can I somehow force the codeception to check the all text in the element?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with `dontSee()`. However, you can get around this limitation by grabbing the element inner text into a variable with `grabTextFrom()`:

```
$elementInnerText = $I->grabTextFrom('ul li');
\PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals($elementInnerText, 'Car A 1');
```

This will give you full control of your string assertions.